# tx_news: Detail view always renders the article first viewed

Tags: typo3, tx-news

T3 8.7.15 with latest versions of tx_news and realurl. All was running just fine. Out of a sudden the following happens:

Click the link of a news article from a list view and it renders the detail view and displays everything correctly, as expected. When I then go back and click (any) another article it will again display the article I just view previously and will only display this article anymore, no matter which other I article I choose. It is always the first article rendered that is being displayed (until cache is emptied).

The links are correct according to the article chosen, by the way. However always the first viewed article is displayed, no matter what.

Have deactivated realurl but behavior is same. Clearing all caches did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to `news` and `realurl` there is a special page in the manual of `news`: [RealURL configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html), the advanced configuration includes also some settings related to chache.

Additional you might have to adjust some [general cache-setting](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/QuickStart/Index.html).

Another point is that you've to [clean the cache of `realurl`](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#cache-clean-up) perhaps after having adjusted some settings.

Furthermore there have been some changes related to cache in core and viewhelpers too, I'm just not sure if they apply to `news` in general or to your individual new-templates:

- [Remove option cHashIncludePageId from cHash calculation](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80050)
- [Make cHash configurable in Fluid Widget Links](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84537)
  Concerning this issue you've to verify your templates if they use any applying viewhelper.

If all hints never help to remove the undesired caching-behavior the simplest workaround is to disable the cache on the news-pages completely till a solution is found. I will update this answer if I find further information. Here is how to disable the page cache for a single page:

1. Open the page-settings of the page(s) where the news-plugin is resided
2. Navigate to the tab "Behavior"
3. Adjust the cache-settings

Comment: Please add a comment what exactly solved your problem. I have the same problem but from the answer I tried a lot and can not figure out how to solve it.

Comment: In general you've to allow cHash in FrontEnd. It's possible to suppress the display of it in FE but nevertheless it's stored and used. Actually it's not really important for me anymore as I work with Version 9.5, there is realUrl not working at all but another solution existing.